# inserting three columns in a table at a time in mysql using select and values

Tags: python, mysql

I need to insert in three columns of a table in mysql at a time. First two columns are inserted by selecting data from other tables by using select statement while the third column needs to be inserted directly and it doesn't need any select. I don't know its syntax in mysql. pos is an array and i need to insert it simultaneously.
here is my sql command in python.
sql="insert into quranic_index_2(quran_wordid,translationid,pos) select quranic_words.wordid,quran_english_translations.translationid from quranic_words, quran_english_translation where quranic_words.lemma=%s and quran_english_translations.verse_no=%s and
quran_english_translations.translatorid="%s,values(%s)"

data=l,words[2],var1,words[i+1]

r=cursor.execute(sql,data)

data is passing variables in which all the variables are stored.       words[i+1] holds values for pos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using below sample query :**

```
INSERT INTO table_name(field_1, field_2, field3) VALUES 
('Value_1', (SELECT value_2,from user_table ), 'value_3')
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select quranic_words.wordid,quran_english_translations.translationid from qurani' at line 1"

Comment: is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: i need where clause with it as well.

Comment: INSERT INTO test.profile_images
 ( 
 contractor_id,
 building_id, 
 image
 )
 
 SELECT contractor_id,'nitin','sharma' FROM profile_images WHERE image=4

Comment: 'nitin','sharma'   are these values or column names?

Comment: these are the 2 string values/constant values assuming you have three columns 2 columns you are inserting String values say 'nitin';'sharma' and third column you are populating from select statement